# Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element. VSCode Live Server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using **VSCode live server**, and **react** & **react-dom**(both version 17) for my project.

**My html code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>React Tutorial</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
        <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My index.js:**https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/gWWZgR?editors=0010
I tried placing <**script**> at the bottom of <**body**>, but it keeps throwing this error:

> Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element.

Comment: Consider sharing the actual code of `index.js` that is causing that error. Share a [mcve].

Comment: May you share the code, not a link?

Comment: @evolutionxbox My code is too long to post, and I have no idea where is the error...

Comment: Then your first step is to do some debugging to find out where the error is. The error should say where it's coming from.

Comment: You are missing the root div in index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `root` div in your `index.html`.
By looking at the code of index.js,

```
ReactDOM.render(<Game />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

You are trying to mount the react app on a div with id='root' which does not exist in the index.html file and thats why the error `Uncaught Error: Target container is not a DOM element. VSCode Live Server` since the element doesn’t exists.

Add
`<div id='root'></div>` to your index.html body.